# iOS 7 -(void)setupAlertCtr:(NSString*)choseMenuType compatibility

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)setupAlertCtr:(NSString*)choseMenuType
    {
        self.alertContForNew = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"İptal" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                 {

                                 }];

       [self.alertContForNew addAction:cancel];
    }
```

This code work on iOS 8 but when i try to use on iOS 7 get crash whats the problem ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `UIAlertController` is only support for iOS 8 and later, in iOS 7 we still have to use `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView`

so you have to put condition like below

```
if (ios8)// change your condition which check ios8 or later.
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                    }];

    UIAlertAction* alertAction1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Your title" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                      //do what you want
                                   }];

    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [alert addAction:alertAction1];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Your Title",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

and for iOS 7 you have to implement `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` and its method

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
          //do what you want.
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```